# How to delete multiple images at once in S3 bucket with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a s3 bucket named `uploads` with millions of images, I want to remove specific names from these images.

```
E.g 
Anyimagesname-100x70.jpg
Anyimagesname-218x150.jpg
Anyimagesname-324x160.jpg
....
```

Then I have a script that specifically handles deleting such files:

```
# !/bin/bash
for imageWithSize in $(find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*-[[:digit:]]{1,9}x[[:digit:]]{1,9}(@2x)?.(jpg|jpeg|png|eps|gif)" -type f); do
    echo rm $imageWithSize >> result.txt
    rm $imageWithSize
done
```

But I don't know how to do it with AWS S3 Cli.

Maybe like this:

```
aws s3 rm s3://uploads/ --dryrun --recursive --exclude "*" --include ".*-[[:digit:]]{1,9}x[[:digit:]]{1,9}(@2x)?.(jpg|jpeg|png|eps|gif)"
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

No, the AWS CLI cannot accept complex regex expressions.

You could write a script like this:

```
import boto3
import re

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET)

# Get a list of object Keys
keys = [object['Key'] for object in response['Contents']]

# Find keys like: Anyimagesname-100x70.jpg
pattern = '.*-[\d]{1,9}x[\d]{1,9}(@2x)?.(jpg|jpeg|png|eps|gif)'
keys_to_delete = [key for key in keys if re.search(pattern, key)]

print(keys_to_delete)

# Delete them!
keys_dict = [{'Key':key} for key in keys_to_delete]
if keys_dict:
    s3_client.delete_objects(Bucket=BUCKET, Delete={'Objects': keys_dict})
```

Please note that `list_objects_v2()` returns 1000 objects at a time, so if you have more files you will need to add pagination code using `ContinuationToken`.

Comment: I do need `ContinuationToken`. Maybe can refer to the code of this page [alexwlchan](https://alexwlchan.net/2018/01/listing-s3-keys-redux/) and combine them together?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein I try to combine and run it but something is going wrong... I am new for this

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for asking questions, but it is not a site for asking people to write code for you. If you have a particular problem with your code, you are welcome to create a new Question and provide full details. However, the best way to learn something is to try and figure it out yourself!